# How to use html5 onerror function in ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

i am building a video app with ionic, I want to play a video, but if the video is not available, I will like to use the onerror fi=unction to change the video source so it will play another video, here is my code

```
<video src="test.mp4" (onerror)="this.src='{{service.ApiURL+video.vid_path}}'"></video>
```

I got this error in the console

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
    Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 10 in [this.src='{{service.ApiURL+video.vid_path}}'] in ng:///HomePage/template.html@28:45 
   <video src="test.mp4" (onerror)="[ERROR ->]this.src='{{service.ApiURL+video.vid_path}}'"
```

Please what am I doing wrong, how can i solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

you are better off doing this with a function rather than embedding logic in template.

```
 <video src="test.mp4" (onerror)="setSource(this)"></video>
```

In your component:

```
 setSource(element) {
  element.src = this.service.apiURL + this.video.vid_path;
 }
```